# yii\rbac\DbManager setup

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

Trying to set up the DbManager for Yii2.  there are lots of threads about the php version, however, not much about the DB version.

What I do know:

Step 1: migrate script

```
./yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations/
```

Step 2: configuration

```
...
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
    'defaultRoles' => ['admin', 'user', 'guest'],
],
...
```

Step 3: set up roles / rules

```
????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

    // add "createPost" permission
    $createPost = $auth->createPermission('createPost');
    $createPost->description = 'Create a post';
    $auth->add($createPost);

    // add "updatePost" permission
    $updatePost = $auth->createPermission('updatePost');
    $updatePost->description = 'Update post';
    $auth->add($updatePost);

    // add "author" role and give this role the "createPost" permission
    $author = $auth->createRole('author');
    $auth->add($author);
    $auth->addChild($author, $createPost);

    // add "admin" role and give this role the "updatePost" permission
    // as well as the permissions of the "author" role
    $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
    $auth->add($admin);
    $auth->addChild($admin, $updatePost);
    $auth->addChild($admin, $author);

    // Assign roles to users. 1 and 2 are IDs returned by IdentityInterface::getId()
    // usually implemented in your User model.
    $auth->assign($author, 2);
    $auth->assign($admin, 1);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Comment: this is exactly how PhpManager works, you do the same thing for dbmanager? where does this go? in the same rbac file created for phpmanager?  whats the real difference between the two if they are the same?

Comment: PhpManager and DbManager implements one interface ManagerInterface! See this link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-managerinterface.html

Comment: that's a great link Oleg.  but I'm still not sure what the difference is between the two if you create both DBManager and PhpManager in the exact same way.

Comment: See this link https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rbac/DbManager.php, run the code that I gave and check your db.